# Seamonkey won't open links from Skype

Tags: skype, seamonkey

when I open a link from Skype in Seamonkey, it won't open the link, but opens the temporary copy of the webpage from my harddisk.

the link in SM looks like 
file:///var/tmp/kdecache-dimitry/......

In Firefox the kink opens fine.

Is there anything to do about this issue?